# алгоритм поиска в ширину

Tags: java, алгоритм

Никак не могу понять, как осуществить поиск в ширину, чтобы находить кратчайший путь в лабиринте. Не могу разобраться с этими очередями т.п. 
Может кто, пожалуйста, может помочь и написать алгоритм? Очень срочно нужно

Вот реализация моего поиска. Метод принимает на вход два параметра - координаты начальной точки. В моем случает это (2, 0). Я не могу разобраться с очередями этими. Я хочу сначала выводить в консоль массив и там отображать кратчайший путь, а потом на основе этого, по тем же индексам передвигать смайлик в лабиринте

```
  public void findPath(int x,int y) {
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>> queue = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>();
        queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x,y));
        mas[x][y] = 1;
        while (queue.size() > 0)  {
            Pair<Integer,Integer> cur = queue.remove(queue.size() - 1);

//
            if (x < width - 1 && mas[x + 1][y] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x+1, y));
                mas[x+1][y] = 1;
            }
            if (x > 0 && mas[x - 1][y] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x-1,y));
                mas[x-1][y] = 1;
            }
            if (y < height - 1 && mas[x][y+1] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x, y + 1));
                mas[x][y+1] = 1;
            }
            if (y > 0 && mas[x][y-1] == 0) {
                queue.add(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(x, y - 1));
                mas[x][y-1] = 1;
            }
//
        }
    }
```

Comment: а в чём именно возникла проблема? Алгоритм достаточно простой и известный.

Comment: pavel Не могу понять его реализацию. Уже пересмотрел все сайты. Никак не могу понять, как его можно применить в моем лабиринте, чтобы смайлик с поставленной точки доходил до выхода.

Answer (score 2):

Ясно, у вас есть более-менее правильный алгоритм поиска в ширину и вам нужно восстановление пути. Предлагаю это делать  отдельной функцией, на самом деле массива `mas` более чем достаточно для восстановления ответа, поэтому смысла меня функцию я не вижу. Параметры функции - *конечная* точка. Путь будет с конца, думаю развернуть не проблема.

```
public void getPath(int x,int y){
    while (mas[x][y] > 1){
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        if (x < width - 1 && mas[x + 1][y] == mas[x][y] - 1) {
            x++;
            continue;
        }
        if (x > 0 && mas[x - 1][y] == mas[x][y] - 1) {
            x--; 
            continue;
        }
        if (y < height - 1 && mas[x][y+1] == mas[x][y] - 1) {
            y++;
            continue;
        }
        if (y > 0 && mas[x][y-1] == mas[x][y] - 1) {
            y--;
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x + " " + y); 
}
```

Comment: Как понять восстановление пути? Коллекции не нужны в алгоритме вообще никакие?

Comment: Как-то привык писать "восстановление ответа", когда нужно не только число в ответ но и план как его получить. Это из динамического программирования пошло.

Comment: @Rynkovoy ну я в консоль вывожу, вам думаю сохранять понадобится. Но это уже мелочи.

Comment: мне не нужно сохранять. простот вывести в лабиринте путь)

Comment: ну это и выводит.